# Disposable wrapper class for PInvoke structure with handles

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, marshalling, dispose

While reading through some of my PInvoke code, I've found that [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) uses a special class to ensure proper disposal of [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873(v=vs.85).aspx) structure handles, because those should be closed by the caller:

> Handles in PROCESS_INFORMATION must be closed with CloseHandle when
>   they are no longer needed.

With `CreateProcess` as:

```
[DllImport(DllNames.Kernel32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "CreateProcess")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern Boolean TryCreateProcess(
    [In] [Optional] String lpApplicationName,
    [In] [Out] [Optional] StringBuilder lpCommandLine,
    [In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    [In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] Boolean bInheritHandles,
    [In] ProcessCreationFlags dwCreationFlags,
    [In] [Optional] IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    [In] [Optional] String lpCurrentDirectory,
    [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    [Out] PROCESS_INFORMATION_DisposableWrapper lpProcessInformation);
```

And `PROCESS_INFORMATION_DisposableWrapper` as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class PROCESS_INFORMATION_DisposableWrapper: IDisposable
{
    private readonly PROCESS_INFORMATION _value;
    private Boolean _isDisposed = false;

    ~PROCESS_INFORMATION_DisposableWrapper()
    {
        this.Dispose(isDisposing: false);
    }

    public PROCESS_INFORMATION Value
    {
        get
        {
            this.ThrowIfDisposed();

            return this._value;
        }
    }

    protected void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (this._isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("PROCESS_INFORMATION has been already disposed");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(isDisposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean isDisposing)
    {
        if (this._isDisposed)
            return;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Disposing");
        // No LastError checking because CreateProcess may fail and those handles will be invalid.
        WinApi.Handle.TryCloseHandle(this.Value.hThread);
        WinApi.Handle.TryCloseHandle(this.Value.hProcess);

        this._isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

So it can be used(through convenience telescoping overload) like:

```
using (var processData = new WinApi.ProcessAndThread.PROCESS_INFORMATION_DisposableWrapper())
{
    var isCreated = WinApi.ProcessAndThread.TryCreateProcess(
        @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe",
        "",
        creationFlags: WinApi.ProcessAndThread.ProcessCreationFlags.NONE,
        startUpInfo: WinApi.ProcessAndThread.STARTUPINFO.Create(),
        processInformationDisposable: processData);

    Console.WriteLine(isCreated);
}
```

It seems to correctly dispose/close valid handles, but I don't like that `_isDisposed` flag. I can't get rid of it, so to not close the handles twice, but whether it is a reliable way to get deterministic and handy disposal I'm not sure.

**So, the question is:** Is it a reliable solution? Or is there a better way?

Perhaps with `SafeHandle` fields in `PROCESS_INFORMATION` instead of `IntPtr`, but that didn't work for me (handle field turned to be null).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public SafeProcessHandle hProcess;
    public SafeThreadHandle hThread;
    public UInt32 dwProcessId;
    public UInt32 dwThreadId;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be setting `_isDisposed = true` inside `Dispose(bool isDisposing)`, you should set it in `Dispose()`. If its the finalizer calling `Dispose(false)` you don't really care about that flag at all, and reducing finalizer code to minimum is always a good idea...you are in shaky ground.

Comment: make a class `class ProcessInformation_SafeHandle: SafeHandle`, this class provides IntPtr handle of `PROCESS_INFORMATION`, extract struct from that handle to get `ProcessInformation` value. override ReleaseHandle, this must close both `hThread` and `hProcess` and should return true if both closed successfully, otherwise return false. this method should not throw exception. Also you should override `IsInvalid` property which will determine if handle is invalid or already closed.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It should probably work, and seems to be better than the current solution. Perhaps you can make a prototype and add it as an answer?

Comment: I cant test if it works or not. if you managed to answer your own question with this way or other ways I appreciate to know and I will upvote that too ;)